# Maven Profiling for Parent Tags

Tags: java, maven, parent, profile

I'm currently using Maven profiles to try and reduce the number of dependencies in the final jar file after compilation.

The problem is the parent tag. Is there a way to make it so the parent tag is only used when using a specific profile?

```
<project xmlns=...

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    **Want to move this parent tag down into profiles**
    *<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>X.X.X</version>
    </parent>*

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Spring Boot Profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>Spring Boot</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                ...
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                ...
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>Example</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    ...
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <!-- Default Build -->
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                ...
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    ...
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I am aware of the use of two separate pom files and the use of the -f flag, however I would prefer to keep everything to a single file.

TLDR: Is there a way to specify the parent tag within a profile?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use parent in profile from a pure maven standpoint, however since we're talking about the spring boot parent starter here, there is a way to define spring boot dependencies, without using the parent tag. This is called BOM, and instead of `parent` you can use the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>X.X.X.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

See [The Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using-import)

I think this can be defined in specific profiles.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in compilation errors :(

Comment: Well, this probably points on some other issue with the poms. I'm not sure whether you better update a question with the errors and details of poms here or its better to ask a separate question for that... Strictly speaking, the answer to your question is that 'parent' tag can't be used in profiles, and that's it. Of course if you decide to go with a separate question - feel free to post a link to it here, so that I could see it and try to come up with an idea of solving that